# For Loop endless

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I'm trying to place every entry from range N2:N200 in a form text box but it would only return 1 entry and when I run the macro the for each loop won't stop.

```
TextBox11.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N2")
    For Each x In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N2:N200")
        If x <> "" Then

            If x1 = "" Then
                x1 = x
            Else
                x1 = x1 & vbCr & Chr(13) & x
            End If

        End If

    Next
```

Comment: where did `x1` come from? Why aren't you declaring your variables? And also what's the point of entering 200 values into 1 Textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changning you code to something like this:

```
Sub FillTextBox()
    Dim Str As String
    TextBox11.MultiLine = True
    For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N2:N200")
        Str = Str & cell.Value & Chr(13)
    Next cell
    TextBox11.Text = Str
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply i actually found the error, its the textbox referrence was incorrect thats why it wasnt displaying... sometimes the simplest things make your head spin... Ill the code above for something else =)